# Excel: IFS or Nested If Statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, ifs

I'm having an issue writing an IFS statement in Excel.

This is what I would like to happen: User chooses from a list of 8 names in B1.  Based on the selection of B1, in B2 the user will get a dropdown of a more refined list to choose from.

This is how I have the IFS statement written so far, which is causing trouble:

=IFS(B1="A",A),["B",B],["C",C],["D",D],["E",E],["F",F],["G",G],["H",H])

I have also written this which doesn't work either:

=IFS(B1="A",A),[B1="B",B],[B1="C",C],[B1="D",D],[B1="E",E],[B1="F",F],[B1="G",G],[B1="H",H])

I keep getting error messages.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: you have to use dependent drop down list, so search on that.

Comment: I figured it out, My formula should be:

=IFS(B1="A",A,B1="B",B,B1="C",C,B1="D",D,B1="E",E,B1="F",F,B1="G",G,B1="H",H)

No brackets I guess?  I don't know why this is working but I'll take it.

Answer (score 1):

In such situations, you can also use a combination of `choose` and `match`. It is more readable and easier to maintain:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(B1,{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"},0), "Action A", "Action B", "Action C", "Action D", "Action E", "Action F", "Action G")
```

It first matches user's choice with a list of options (you can also specify the list as a range of cells in your sheet). Then it chooses the action based on that selection.

Answer (score 0):

The common way is with dependant drop down lists. Very easy.

Consider a simplified example.

You have 8 initial options A-H. This will be the source list for your first data validation drop down. Then for each of the selections in that list you will create a named range of the same name as the selection.

So named range called `A`, `B` etc.

Then for the second drop down data validation you put List and as Source you put Indirect(cell containing first data validation list)

So in the example below:

[image: Example]

The initial drop down list is in C1 and its source is column E

[image: Initial list]

You can see in the top left name manager box that the highlighted range in column `G` is named as `A`.

The second drop down cell `D1` has the source formula `=INDIRECT($C$1)`

So when `A` is selected in `C1` then data validation in D1 comes from Indirect to named range `A` which is the list in column `G`.

[image: Indirect to range A]